# QGIS Quickly switching overlapping raster images

Tags: qgis, raster, layers

I'm new to QGIS, and haven't used arcGIS in about 5 years, however I've just seen someone using arcGIS and was able to quickly switch between overlapping rasters when checking registration. The top half of the screen was one raster, and the bottom was another, and the mouse was used to move up and down in real time switching between the two (I'm probably not explaining this very well).

The images I'm working with are very large (2x1GB geotiffs) and of the same area. There is a good 5second lag between switching layers which makes it difficult to see if there is good alignment.

Does this functionality exist in QGIS, to quickly switch rasters in real time?

Comment: Does anyone knows if there is still no flicker option in QGIS, I work with very high resolution deforestation monitoring corrections and in order to concentrate 100% in the visual change detection, Flicker is the way to go, MapSwipe Tool requires you to move your mouse instead of being drawing/correcting the observed deforestations while flicker is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for it is "swipe" functionality for QGIS. I'm sorry but still isn’t a plugin for that. In the meanwhile you can try this plugin:

[Raster Transparency](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/raster_transparency/). It allow you to change transparency interactively.

Comment: I see. Not quite as clean as the 'swipe' thing but it does seem to work. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

From the below link you can download the swipe plugin for QGIS

Tool name is "MapSwipe Tool"

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mapswipetool_plugin/